# Keep Alive Database connection to avoid Communication link failure Exception

Tags: java, mysql

I am running the jar of spring boot maven project contains REST API's in dedicated server, I am trying to get data from the database of hosting server.
Version of mysql in hosting server: 4.1.35

For first few minutes everything is fine, but after that i am getting error like this.

Error in postman:
{
  "timestamp": "2019-05-14T16:42:03.732+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "Communications link failure\n\nThe last packet successfully received from the server was 473,282 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 9 milliseconds ago.",
  "path": "/api/master/NotificationList"
}

Error in Server:

Request processing failed; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 473,282 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 9 milliseconds ago. with root cause

I am using commons-dbcp and mysql-connector-jar

```
private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://XXX.XXX.XXX.X:3306/dbname?useSSL=false&allowMultiQueries=true&autoReconnect=true";
private static String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static String username = "username";
private static String password = "password";

GenericObjectPool connectionPool = new GenericObjectPool(null);

public DataSource setUp() throws Exception
{
    Class.forName(ConnectionManager.driverName).newInstance();

    connectionPool.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(1000 * 60 * 30);
    connectionPool.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(1000 * 60 * 30);
    connectionPool.setNumTestsPerEvictionRun(3);
    connectionPool.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    connectionPool.setTestWhileIdle(true);
    connectionPool.setTestOnReturn(false);
    connectionPool.setMaxActive(-1);

    ConnectionFactory cf = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory( ConnectionManager.url, ConnectionManager.username, ConnectionManager.password);
    PoolableConnectionFactory poolableConnectionFactory = new PoolableConnectionFactory(cf, connectionPool, null, "SELECT 1", false, true);
    return new PoolingDataSource(connectionPool);
}

public GenericObjectPool getConnectionPool()
{
    return connectionPool;
}
```

```
pom.xml


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: what does `connectionPool.setMaxActive(-1);` do ?

Comment: Why do you create your own connection pool?